# Assigning an Excel Shape an RGB Color - Optimize my routine

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to set a Shape Color to the color of an associated cell from a lookup in VBA.  i.e.:

```
CellColor = Worksheets("Config").Range("C5").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```

Provides me with a color that I can use to assign to a shape:

```
With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.rgb = CellColor
```

What I can't get to work is looking up a respective cell and then assigning the associated color...  I have a Configuration Tab with 2 columns, Category and Color.  The Category column is a list of categories.  Next to that is a column of the colors that I want assigned to the Category, meaning that the color is physically visible to the user, not a name or numeric referencing the color.

I'd like to do something like the below where the txtImpactCategory is the field I need to drive the lookup of the Shape color:

```
CellColor = WorksheetFunction.Lookup(txtImpactCategory, Worksheets("Config").Range("B2:B12").Value, Worksheets("Config").Range("C2:C12").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color)
```

When I do this, I get a Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the Lookup property of the WorksheetFunction class.

If I change the above lookup to return the Value of column C2:C12, i.e. Worksheets("Config").Range("C2:C12").Value it returns the text in that field so programmatically it's executing the lookup properly.  I just can't get the color to return.

Any help direction would be appreciated.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Use `Range.Find`. Find the category in column B, then use `Offset` to refer to the corresponding range in column C.

Comment: Perfect!  CellColor = Worksheets("Config").Range("B2:B12").Find(txtImpactCategory).Offset(0, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color

Comment: I'd assign the 'FIND' part to a separate range variable so you can check it found something (`IF NOT rangevariable IS NOTHING THEN`) .  As it is it will throw an error if nothing is found.  Also give the other `FIND` parameters a value or it will use whatever you used last (even using Ctrl+F on a worksheet) - you've set the `What` parameter, but need the `After`, `LookIn`, `LookAt` parameters filled.  [FIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)